# WebInvoke Post Error : Method Not Allowed

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created one WCF Data Service with simple entity as below.

```
namespace DataService
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class MemoryPackageData
{
    public long c1 { get; set; }
    public long c2 { get; set; }
    public long c3 { get; set; }
    public long c4 { get; set; }
}
}
```

```html
namespace DataService
{
    public class WCFDataService : DataService<DBEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MemoryPackageDatas", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("InsertEntityData", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }

        //[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "InsertEntityData/?package_id={package_id}&package_size={package_size}")]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "InsertEntityData?package_id={package_id}")]
        public void InsertEntityData(Int64 package_id, Int64 package_Size = 10)
        {
// some stuff
}
```

Now, when I run this service in firefox and pass one parameter which is mandatory in the URL.

[image]

I have tried many different ways to call this method here. But not sure how to deal with these parameters list.

Method is inserting data to table.

Can any one please guide me here?

Thank you,

Mittal.

Answer (score 0):

WebInvoke considers Method="POST" by default.
So you can use either WebGet attribute or specify Method="GET"

Comment: But I am inserting data to the database. I am not retrieving data. Still I keep it as GET ?

Comment: did you check on REST client using "POST" method?

Answer (score 0):

In browser, the default method is "Get". That's why the service will return 405.
You can use Fiddler to compose a Request with "Post" and try.